# Excel - Select only cells in column(38) from selected rows

Tags: vba, excel, select

I have a 10k rows selected in my spreadsheet. Now I need to narrow down that selection to only the cells in column 38 from the previous selection.

I have almost zero experience with VBA but the macro I used to select the rows was

```
Sub selectwholerow()
Selection.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

So I guess what I'm looking for sort of along the lines of

```
Sub selectcolumn()
Selection.Columns(38).Select
End Sub
```

But I have no clue really.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes it brought me to the column after running it, but only selects one cell @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub selectcolumn()
    Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns(38), Selection.EntireRow).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to `Select` the intersection, you could use:

```
Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Columns(38)).Select
```

If you want to do something else with that specified range, then you could use a function to return it:

```
Function Col38(ByRef r As Range) As Range
    Set Col38 = Intersect(r.EntireRow, Columns(38))
End Function
```

Then use something like:

```
Sub Test()
    Col38(Selection).Select
End Sub
```